# Testing types in union type

Tags: typescript

I need to parse all keys of an object and call different methods based on the type of their values.

Does typescript automatically propagate types i've already tested it for in an union type? How does this work?

```js
const filters: {
  [keys: string]: string | Array<any>
} = {
  stringParam: 'string',
  arrayParam: ['1', '2']
}

const params = Object.entries(filters)
  .map(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v) ?
    arrayParameterizer(v) :
    stringParameterizer(v))

arrayParameterizer(param: Array<any>) {
  // Some code
}

stringParameterizer(param: string) {
  // Some code
}
```

Comment: `[]` is the type of a zero-length [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) and unlikely to be applicable to what you're doing.  If you want to accept an arbitrary array you can say `any[]` or `Array<any>`.  If you want an array of strings you can say `string[]` or `Array<string>`.

Comment: In fact I'd say this is your problem, not anything to do with "casting" per se.  If I fix it to use `string[]`, then [it works with no issue](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3vLN).

Comment: @jcalz: Post it as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz that's not the issue here, even declaring that it could be an Array<any> it still complains that the arrayParameterizer can't take a ```string | Array<any>``` because it need an ```Array<any>```

Comment: @brightpants what do you mean? The example jcalz posted does work - there is no error with `arrayParameterizer`.

Comment: @H.B. I think I spoke too soon about it being the problem... I would post it as an answer but the error reported in the question is [not reproducible](https://tsplay.dev/KwXr8m).  I'd suggest that brightpants make sure this is a [mcve] and then someone can answer it.

Comment: I'm getting "Argument of type string|Array<any> is not assignable to type string" error

Comment: That should work, if you get `string|Array<any>` your argument is not property type guarded. `Array.isArray` should do that, if it does not you are probably using an old version of TypeScript which does not have the type guard (`arg is any[]`).

Comment: @H.B. I'm sorry, you're right. Vscode is kinda buggy here. Closed everything up, restarted the computer and now it compiles with no issues. Thank you very much!

Comment: @H.B. also, I didn't know the type actually propagated like that, if anything I can reenter the question in some other way and you can type this info here. I learned something new today! Thank you all.

Comment: @jcalz: Post it, maybe add the bit about how it acts as a type guard to explain how that works.

Comment: I've edited the question to be about the type guard, so you guys can post an answer about it! It was kind of hard to find material about this issue.

Comment: @H.B. is it possible for me to create myself something like the isArray which removes the array type from the union?

Comment: @brightpants Not sure if removing is something you can do, usually they are just asserting that a value is something specific. [See the documentation for more info.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223166/discussion-between-brightpants-and-h-b).

Comment: It’s totally ok to answer your own question so you should write up an answer explaining what you’ve found.  Because after reading these comments I don’t know if there is still a question or if you’ve resolved everything.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Done! I still can't accept my own answer but it's there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems typescript has a feature called Type Guards.

As per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), you can declare a function that returns a `type predicate`, and it can be implemented as such:

```js
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

And, when using a function that returns a type predicate (`Array.isArray()` being one of them) to test for types, typescript automatically understands that the variable can't be of that type explicited in the type guard.

So, in the following example

```js
let unionVar: number | string | Array<any>
const var = Array.isArray() 
            ? unionVar // unionVar is of type Array<any> 
            : unionVar // unionVar here is of type number | string
```

It can be reproduced by yourself using the `var is Type` declaration in the return type of the function!